# Howto reinstall Eclipse SDK?

Tags: eclipse

I want to learn java but i can't even run my project in AVD. I'm always getting some different compile/SDK errors even when im trying to run blank project. Tried to remove all entities in SDK manager and reinstall them but it didn't helped, its only got worse.
So i gonna try to reinstall Eclipse and JRE.
Wanted to automatically remove eclipse but couldn't find the "uninstall" file in SDK folder, and i can't find the Eclipse in windows control panel.
Is there any tool that will help me fully uninstall Eclipse? That's sad when u can't compile even blank "Hello World" app :c
Sorry for my lame English, i'm Ukrainian. (=

Answer (score 1):

There is no uninstall file for Eclipse. Just delete the installation folder.